# Trying to build a one to one relationship between two preexisting models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I am trying to build a one to one relationship between two preexisting models (test and test_type) in rails.

Here is my workflow.

```
has_one :test_type - to tests model
belongs_to :test - to test_types model
rails g migration Add_Test_Type_To_Test test_type:references 
rake db:migrate
```

Now that looks like it has worked ok but when I try to verify that it looks like it hasn't.

```
rails console
@type = TestTypes.new :name => "My Type"
@type.save
@test = Tests.new :name => "My Test"

TestTypes.find(1) //returns record ok
@test.test_type //returns nil
@test.test_type = TestTypes.find(1) //NameError: uninitialized constant Tests::TestType
@test.test_type //still nil
```

According to the output it finds my type in the database but it doesn't seem to be able to  add it to my test class which indicates to me that the relationship is not working.

Is anybody able to tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With the given associations,you will be having `test_id` in `test_types` table and you wont be having `test_type_id` in your `tests` table.I would recommend to see these guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I will actually never be referencing from type to test hence the lack of an testid on the type. Would this cause any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you just change one line of code `belongs_to :test` -> `has_one :test` to make it one-on-one relationship. But I think your error comes from the fact that you have not added *test_type* instance to *test_type* attribute of *test* object. So before making `@test.test_type` request you need to add it `@test.test_type = @test_type`. If you wanna save the change to database then `update_attribute` method is very useful for that purpose [update_attribute(name, value)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute), `@test.update_attribute('test_type', @test_type)`

**Updated** answer: [Rails Guide says](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference):

4.2.1 Methods Added by has_one

When you declare a has_one association, the declaring class automatically gains five methods related to the association:

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {}
```

so try this `@test.create_test_type(test_id: test.id)`, that bit of code can replace the following code I mentioned earlier `@test.test_type` (sorry I'm not Rails expert - still learning)

Comment: I have modified my models to both use the has_one association however unfortunately it hasn't helped with this issue.

Comment: Also I am trying to add the testtype object to the test object in the example above like you suggested but I am getting the following error: @test.test_type = TestTypes.find(1) //NameError: uninitialized constant Tests::TestType

Comment: I think if you use [@]test.test_type = [@]test_type, then you don't need to use this code any more: [@]test.test_type = TestTypes.find(1)  .. However I'm not sure if you are still using that bit of code. (sorry for my confusion). Note I had to use square brackets [@] the get this comment accepted

Comment: Okay I checked this one out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference So try this @test.create_test_type(test_id = test.id)